# How to import a value from sql to a variable value? TypeError: An integer is requied (got type list)

Tags: python, sql, list, int, typeerror

I'm in the process of creating a counter that writes the value to a database, then I want to load the maximum value written at the next reboot.

My problem is when i execute my sql query i'll get a "list" insted and error "TypeError: An integer is requied (got type list).

`counter=Value('h', 0)`

`SELECT MAX(counter) FROM [TTMM].[dbo].[280]
counter.value = cursor.fetchall()
print(counter.value)`

Result if i use a string as output variable insted: [ 267, ].

Just want to get 267 as my counter value.

How do i convert a list to int?

Comment: result = counter.value[0]?

Comment: @Wimanicesir, Then i get "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Then counter.value is a integer.. Are you sure you get a list in return?

Comment: @Wimanicesir yea that's what error log says.

Comment: Well I don't know what the problem actually is anymore. You want to convert a list to an integer but in my opinion that variable is already an integer. I'm very sorry but can you explain your problem again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple... i was cursor.fetchone insted of fetchall.

My solution:

```
counter=Value('h', 0)

SELECT MAX(counter) FROM [TTMM].[dbo].[280]
counter.value = cursor.fetchone()[0]
print(counter.value)
```